# JEDI JCL runtime compiler error E2040 when using JclWin32.hpp

Tags: c++builder, jedi

I have installed the current stable JEDI Code library in C++ Builder XE3 on Windows 7 x32. It works fine, but only as long as I don't include files like JclFileUtils.hpp which are including **JclWin32.hpp**. Then I get always the **compiler error E2040: "Declaration terminated incorrectly"** (in file JclWin32.hpp, line 682, second line in the following code snippet):

```
#define NetApi32 L"netapi32.dll"
static const System::Int8 CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILESX86 = System::Int8(0x2a);
#define RT_MANIFEST (System::WideChar *)(0x18)
```

I neither have an idea were this error comes from, nor could I found any hints to this. What could be the cause? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got help and the solution for this problem. Just replace the static const declaration:

```
static const System::Int8 CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILESX86 = System::Int8(0x2a);
```

with this macro definition:

```
#define CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILESX86 0x2a
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in `JclWin32.pas`.

In C/C++, the Win32 API declares `CSIDL` values in Microsoft's `shlobj.h` header using preprocessor `#define` statements, eg:

```
#define CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILESX86 0x002a
```

After the preprocessor is run and performs `#define` symbol replacements, the compiler ends up seeing the following *invalid* declaration in `JclWin32.hpp`:

```
static const System::Int8 0x002a = System::Int8(0x2a);
```

JCL should not be re-declaring `CSIDL_PROGRAM_FILESX86` (or any other `CSIDL` value) at all. It should be either:

1. using Delphi's own `Winapi.ShlObj` unit, which already declares `CSIDL` values.
2. if not using the `Winapi.ShlObj` unit, then it should at least be declaring its manual `CSIDL` values as `{$EXTERNALSYM}` so they do not appear in the generated `JclWin32.hpp` file.  If needed, JCL can include an `{$HPPEMIT '#include <shlobj.h>'}` statement to pull in the existing Win32 API declarations for C/C++ projects to use.